# Can we assign return value of function to macro in c

Tags: function, macros, return

I am trying to assign the return value of a function to macro . The model name might change depending on the return value . I know we can assign only constant values to macros. But is there any way I can do this ?

```
#define MODEL get_model_name()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want?
It is impossible to know at compile time the return value of a function.
But if you know what get_model_name will return than you can do this:

```
#define MODEL_NAME "the name"
```

However if you want the macro just to [expand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion) at compile time to the function get_model_name() then you already have that.
look at the code below (assuming get_model_name returns a char*):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MODEL get_model_name()
int main(){
    printf("%s\n",MODEL);
}
```

It will be preprocessed to about the following:

```
//the contents of stdio.h
int main(){
    printf("%s\n",get_model_name());
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I would want the macro to expand at compile time . My function return type is enum and it looks like this   "model_t get_model_name( )" and if do #define MODEL get_model_name() , the compiler is complaining about initializer element is not constant.

Comment: #define MODEL() \
 { \
 int retval;\
 retval = get_model_name(); \
 retval;\
 } I managed to add this code . but still I get an error . What might be wrong with this ?

Comment: can you add a more complete code listing?